# Why CPU usage differs too much between AVD and real device?

Tags: android, performance, android-virtual-device, aac

I have an android app, playing back HLS.
And I'm very curious about why `Android Studio`'s `CPU usage monitor` shows so different loads:

AVD: Kernel: ~2% / User: ~0% :
[image: AVD: Kernel: ~2% / User: ~0%]
My Sony Z3: Kernel: ~5% / User: ~30% :
[image]

And there are no other background services run to load my Z3 so badly, I assure you.
Yep, the only obvious difference I see - AVD uses software decoder `OMX.google.aac.decoder`, but Z3 uses `OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac` (hardware, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

AVD uses the CPU of your computer which is much faster than your phone. So only a few percentage of CPU cycles are required by the AVD whereas more percentage is required in a phone.

Also the decoder's implementation makes the difference. But generally hardware decoder are faster than software decoders. So this should not be the case.

Comment: Am I right that 30% of `User` metrics (that is displayed in the CPU load monitor) actually is 30% of whole CPU of the device? If so, this is awful for just playing back an HLS.. Don't you think?

Comment: Yes, It is. You need to find a different solution for it.